# Extrude without creating new faces

Tags: faces, extrude

Hi, I am new to Blender

I have extruded these faces inward (arrow 1), but I had to come back to adjust it (arrow 2). When I do this I create new faces (with edge and vertices) that create me problem later on. Is there a way to do extrude adjustments without this happening?

[image]

Comment: 2.90 should be addressing this (https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.90/Modeling).

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30874/push-faces-like-sketchup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the point where each vertical edge was at Arrow 1, in edit mode you can shift-select each of those inset vertical edges, and then hit s to scale each edge and push them inwards.  That will move just those edges and their vertices all inwards (or outwards) symmetrically.

If you're already at Arrow 2 and can't go back, from edit mode you can select each horizontal edge at Arrow 1, hit "x" to bring up the delete sub-menu, and select Dissolve Edges to eliminate them.  You can then scale the vertical edges at Arrow 2 using the process above to move them without creating any new edges.

Does this accomplish what you were trying to do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have tried option 2 and it fixed my problems, however option 1 is no substitute for actual extruding.
What matter is that I fixed my problem, thanks :)

Comment: Great - please consider marking this issue accepted.