# Extruding inwards without creating double faces

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm trying to extrude the selected face in Cube #1 by pressing E, left click then move along X axis. The desired result is Cube #3 but what I get is Cube #2. Is there any workaround for this as it seems a very simple problem and I find it weird that this function hasn't been implemented yet.

Thank you in advance!

[image: Example]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30874/push-faces-like-sketchup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and select Extrude Manifold.  Blender will move all the edges of your selection back while creating a new face under the lip, just like you want.